# Object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Tags: r

I am using R (x64 version 3.2.2) on Windows 10 and get the following error message when (see below) trying to subset a very simple dataframe which has many NAs.

```
dt <- read.table("Datos.csv", header=T, sep=",")
k1 <- which(apply(is.na(dt),2,sum) < 10)  #Keep variables with <10 NA's
k2 <- which(apply(is.na(dt[,k1]),1,sum)==0)  #Keep observations with no NA's
dt <- dt[k2,k1] 

Error in dt[k2, k1] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

What would be the reason for this error in my case?

Best. Luciano

Comment: I can't reproduce this error in R 3.3.1 on Mac OS X using the "iris" data set. What you typed should work just fine, although it's bad practice to override existing R functions like `dt`. Either you're leaving out code from your post, or something is wrong with your version of R.

Comment: Also, programming questions are off-topic here. This belongs on StackOverflow using the `r` tag on that site.

Comment: Please add a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1217536) for people to work with.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about how to use R without a reproducible example.

Answer (score 7):

You have assigned an object to the name `dt`.  Unfortunately `dt` is also the name of a [built in R function](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/TDist.html).

Because of R's scoping rules (though, as @ssdecontrol points out in the comments, it's not clear why), the `dt` on the right hand side of your last line resolves to this function, not the data table you created.  A function in R is called a `closure` internally, and you are trying to use the `[` function on it, which is called subsetting.  Hence, you are attempting to subset a closure, **kaboom**.

To resolve, chose a different name for your data table on the first line.

Comment: R scoping is actually pretty sane. It's just that you can cause very bizarre problems with nonstandard evaluation. Assigning `dt` at the top level should uniformly mask the `dt` function for any code being evaluated in the global env. There's more to the story than OP is letting on

Comment: Yah, maybe by "scoping" I really meant "non-standard evaluation", and "lack of an actual import mechanism".  I stand by my opinion that those two things are insane.

Comment: @ssdecontrol I seem to recall, in the depth of my memory, that R keeps functions seperate from other objects in it's name spaces for some purposes.  I must confess though, for anything requiring the delicacy that understanding such mechanisms would require, I just use python.